# Employing numerical techniques for Hotellings location model

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to program a numerical solution for Hotellings locational model (with regards to the firms' respective locations). However, I have very little experience with numerical techniques. Let's assume that we are analyzing a duopoly where the firms:

1. choose locations in the first stage
2. compete in prices in the second stage

Model Specifics:

Notation:

$P_i=prices $

$x_i=locations$

Demand functions

$$F({D_1}) ={ {\frac{{{P_2} - {P_1}}}{{2t({x_2} - {x_1})}} + \frac{{{x_2} + {x_1}}}{2}} }$$

$$F({D_2}) ={1- [{\frac{{{P_2} - {P_1}}}{{2t({x_2} - {x_1})}} + \frac{{{x_2} + {x_1}}}{2}}] }$$

Profit functions

\begin{array}{l}
{\pi _1} = {P_1}F({D_1})\\
{\pi _2} = {P_2}F({D_2})\\
\end{array}

Solving through backward induction.

First-order conditions:

$$FO{C_1} =\frac{-2\,P_1+P_2+\left(x1+x2\right)\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{2\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}$$

$$FO{C_2} =\frac{P_1-2\,P_2+\left(- x1-x2+2\right)\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{2\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}$$

Equilibrium prices:

$$P_1=\frac{\left(x1+x2+2\right)\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{3}$$

$$P_2=\frac{\left(- x1-x2+4\right)\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{3}$$

First-stage profit functions:

$${\pi _1}=\frac{\left(x1+x2+2\right)^2\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{18}$$

$${\pi _2}=\frac{\left(x1+x2-4\right)^2\,\operatorname{t}\left(- x1+x2\right)}{18}$$

I am looking for a numerical solution to find the Nash equilibrium for the problem. That is, how do I solve for the optimal locations on the [0,1] interval using numerical analysis? Do you have any tips to which methods I might use to solve it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Notation is confusing. What's what? Generally: parametrize, solve two focs by some solver. Done.